# Writing part of a compiler (written in c++) in Perl

Tags: c++, perl, compiler-construction, programming-languages, lexer

i am trying to learn more about compilers and programming languages, **unfortunately** my university doesnt offer a course about compilers and so i have to do myself (thank you internet).

At the moment im **tryin** to understand and to implement a lexer for my language and i need regular expressions.

I am used to script perl regex pretty quickly and i thought that *i could embed Perl in my C++ lexer*. Now the questions are:

- Will it cause Heavy overhead?
- Should i try to make peace with BOOST (or any other c++ library good gor regex) ?

Thank you for reading this :)

Comment: why not the old good lex/yacc? (well, flex/bison)

Comment: Actually i know about them but i want to get a "deep" understanding of  compilers internals.. i've also read about Quex that looks good too :)

Comment: I've seen a lexer written in Icon, which (like Perl) also has very good string processing, and the need for the power of something like regular expressions is nowhere as strong as you'd think. I'd recommend you find a book that is usually used by universities for compiler-writing courses, such as "Crafting a Compiler in C". I know that one gets very deep inside how a compiler works.

Comment: At the moment i am reading the dragon book (compilers etc etc) i will try to fetch a copy of your book asap :)

Comment: @fatmatto, if you want a *deep*  understanding, you're bound to writing your own regular expressions compiler.

Comment: @SK-logic i found a lot of material about that on the web, thanks for suggesting it :D

Comment: Regexp::Grammars is an interesting CPAN module to learn new Perl regex capabilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No reason you can't, part of being a good programmer is using the right tool for the job, and perl is VERY good at text processing.

However, instead of thinking about stuffing a perl-based lexer into your C++ compiler (written in C++, not compiling C++, I hope), you should think about writing a perl module in C++, and letting the compiler driver be written in perl, do the lexing, fill in data structures, and then call the C++ module's functions to finish the compile.

Comment: this solution sounds very interesting, i could also learn how to "organize" a perl module. Maybe is a dumb question, but why do say "not compiling c++" ? Performance issues or something else?

Comment: @fatmatto: Writing a compiler that can parse C++ is quite hard. Besides, you really don't need regular expressions to lex C++.

Comment: i'm sorry i misread your comment, thanks for explaining that :D 
i want to compile my own defined language, not c++ anyway :)

Comment: @fatmatto: Although @MSalters isn't I, he did correctly explain my meaning.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  sorry for bothering but could you explain me what do you exactly mean with "compiler driver" ? which part of the compiler process should it take care of?

Comment: @fatmatto: The "compiler driver" would handle command line processing and then call the other subroutines, such as "preprocessor", "parser", "lexer", "call resolver", "optimizer", "output generator"

Answer (score 8):

Embedding Perl in your project just to do regular expressions would be like trying to stuff an elephant into a Miata to get more trunk space.  (Badump!)

Boost would be one way to handle regular expressions, or if you're writing in an environment that supports POSIX.2, look into the `regcomp()`, `regexec()` and `regfree()` functions.

After you've written your own lexer, investigate a tool called `lex` which is pretty much the gold standard for developing lexical analyzers.  It has a partner called `YACC` for developing parsers.  Both are time tested and generate tight, bug-free code.  (GNU-ish environments call these programs `flex` and `bison`.)

Answer (score 3):

If all you really want is Perl-style regular expressions, look into the [libpcre](http://www.pcre.org/) library. It's very well tested, very portable, and in my experience easy to work with. Recommended software. (And probably already on your machine. :)

Comment: I missed libpcre, but i found libPerl++ and thats why i made this post. Your suggestion looks more specific for my problem, i will add this libpcre to the todo list ;)

Comment: PCRE does not support many possibilities of Perl regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom of the "What good is \G in a regular expression?" [section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5cG-in-a-regular-expression%3f) of perlfaq6. It describes how //gc can be used to create a tokeniser aka lexer.