# How's Roslyn C# compiler bootstrapped?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compilation, roslyn

I've started reading about "Roslyn" the new C# compiler and was wondering how was the Roslyn compiler compiled?
I understand that [boostrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) is needed in order to have ["self hosting compiler"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_compiler_construction#Self-hosting_compilers), and I wondered how was the Roslyn compiler "bootstrapped"?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already seem know what is bootstrapping. Then what you don't know?

Comment: Seems like opening https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Roslyn.sln in Visual Studio and pushing the "compile" button would do the trick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how it was **actually** (not guessing) done by the C# team, [according to Eric Lippert](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html):

C# 1.0 through 5.0 compilers were written in C++. For quite a long time -- over a year -- we wrote the Roslyn C# compiler in C# and compiled it with C# 4.0. (C# 5.0 was being developed in parallel by a sister team.) The day that we could compile the Roslyn compiler, and then turn right around and compile it again using the compiler we'd just built, that was a happy day.

[Nice piece](https://medium.com/microsoft-open-source-stories/how-microsoft-rewrote-its-c-compiler-in-c-and-made-it-open-source-4ebed5646f98) on the business case for bootstrapping the compiler by Mads Torgersen:

"Here, finally was our value proposition: Make it so that there only needs to be one code base in the world that understands C#, shared by everyone who wants to build tools over code!"

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrapping is only a problem if there isn't already an existing implementation of the language. In this case there was, so it's easy.

1. Compile the first version of Roslyn using the existing C# compiler
2. Then re-compile it using the freshly compiled Roslyn build.
3. Done.

Comment: When new keywords are added to the language, how it will be compiled? because we don't have the compiler(yet) which understands the new tokens ? [Originally asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513234/in-which-language-is-the-c-sharp-compiler-written#comment47395673_27513277)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Just don't use those new features in the compiler (at first).

Comment: Silly me :) It was very easy one :)

Comment: This was somewhat challenging for us -- even though the C# compiler that supported await had shipped, the Roslyn compiler didn't support it yet. We couldn't use it in the IDE codebase because we were trying to get to self-hosting. Now we can use features that we haven't shipped to the entire world yet, but it used to be the reverse!

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the existing C# compiler has been used for this. I mean, a fully bootstrapped compiler is nice but in this case not really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29

> If one needs to obtain a compiler for language X (which is written in
>   language X), there is the issue of how the first compiler can be
>   written. The different methods that are used in practice to solving
>   this chicken or the egg problem include:
>
> Implementing an interpreter or compiler for language X in language Y.
>   Niklaus Wirth reported that he wrote the first Pascal compiler in
>   Fortran.[citation needed] Another interpreter or compiler for X has
>   already been written in another language Y; this is how Scheme is
>   often bootstrapped.

But for the specifics of Roslyn I would guess, built with c# compiler (pre-Roslyn) then built with its self :) (first few runs) once its stable, they probs just build Roslyn with Roslyn :)

I would also guess that its all automated and unit tested.