# Which versions of which compilers I should use to have C# 9 compiler?

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513234/in-which-language-is-the-c-sharp-compiler-written) it was written that compilers of different versions are applied sequentially to build the latest version of compiler.

I don't want to use binaries provided by Microsoft. I want to have everything be compiled from source codes.

Which repositories I should compile exactly? Do they all have open source licenses?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to have everything be compiled from source codes." What is the scope here? What libraries? What platform? Do you really want to replace C# .NET infra-structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime and the compiler for .NET 5.0 are open-source. You can start by going to https://github.com/dotnet/runtime. However, building the runtime requires the compiler (which will be downloaded by running the build script). So there's little you can do to avoid getting binaries that were built by Microsoft. If you're afraid that they're fake (and in some way different from what you would get if you directly built everything from source) you'll probably have to go a different way.