# What language was used to write Rust compiler?

Tags: rust

94% of Rust compiler was written in Rust. So I can't understand how is it possible? Because for compiling rustc you already must have some rust compiler. Can someone explain how it works and how rust compiler was created?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29#The_chicken_and_egg_problem

Comment: This is explained well in an existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193560/writing-a-compiler-in-its-own-language

Answer (score 14):

Simply put, once you have a compiler that compiles code, you can use that to develop and compile a new compiler. That new compiler can "understand" whatever language it's designed to compile.

So, suppose there was some C++ based rust compiler, and rust code was developed that compiles to a rust compiler, once you build that you have a rust based rust compiler.

Comment: I know you are just making a hypothetical situation but initial `Rust` compiler was written in `OCaml` not `C++`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)

Comment: Ocaml was also used for Haxe