# Does any working Seed AI exist

Tags: algorithm, recursion, code-generation, artificial-intelligence

Is anyone aware of any implemented algorithms/programs that could fall under the category of Seed AI? By this I mean "recursive self-improvement."

In the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_AI) they talk about compilers but do other examples exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your linked Wiki article correctly, this is at the moment a hypothetical conept:

> Seed AI is a hypothesized type of strong artificial intelligence...

Also, the compiler example is, as they say, very limited in explaining the concept, as it is only single-step and by definition the Seed AI algorithm should be *infinitely* recursive.

> A limited example is that program language compilers are often used to compile themselves. As compilers become more optimized, they can re-compile themselves and so be faster at compiling.
>
> However, they cannot then produce faster code and ***so this can only provide a very limited one step self-improvement***.

If you want to know anything more, I would suggest having a look at the organizations that are doing active research in this field.

1. [Singularity Institute](http://singinst.org/)
2. [AGIRI.org](http://www.agiri.org/wiki/Main_Page)
3. [Texai](http://www.texai.org/)
4. [Halliburton](http://www.halliburton.com/)

---

**UPDATE**

Consolidated Robotics does the AI (under the name of Consolidated), but they were bought out by Halliburton in 2005.

> In 2005, the privately held Consolidated was acquired by energy conglomerate Halliburton for an estimated price of $25 billion US. The company continues to operate under the name Consolidated, though as a wholly owned and operated division of Halliburton.

Comment: I understand that infinitely recursive optimizing algorithms don't exist but I was interested in one that could perhaps recurse 5 or 10 maybe 20 times. Will follow your links. PS: Halliburton, really? God help us! lol

Comment: Citation for Halliburton? I can't find anything through Google that would suggest they're doing any kind of AI research.

Answer (score -1):

One can build tiny compilers that can be augmented by additional external information.  This is a kind of learning.  One can start extremely small ("seed") and grow the compiler by adding knowledge until it can start acquiring it.  One has to start somewhere, and assuming a seed is already big enough to grow itself without help seems self-defeating; how did it get that way?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676159/120163 for a truly tiny compiler that can be bootstrapped.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11722239)

Comment: I disagree that this doesn't answer the question.   Now we're into opinions.

Comment: IMHO, it did  not look like an answer.   It is valuable as comment. Which is what I voted for.