# How small can we make a compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction

How small can we make a compiler for any (one) language like C, Assembly etc ? Would it be possible to make it about 300-400kb ?

Comment: A "compiler for any language" would certainly not fit in 400kb.

Comment: @Juhana How do we prove that ? Can you also tell me what is the smallest compiler made for C ?

Comment: There are some compilers that take only a few kB. It depends on the language you want to process...

Comment: Sorry, I was being unnecessarily sarcastic. If you mean "one compiler that can compile any (all) languages", then it's impossible to make. If you mean "is there a compiler that is smaller than 400kb (for any single language)", then yes, most compilers are smaller than that. If you mean "can a compiler for any given (single) language be made smaller than 400kb", the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Googling for this lead me to this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630417/what-is-the-conceptually-smallest-compiler-that-can-compile-itself I think your question is completely language dependant. Like `How small can you make a C compiler..?` I assume someone will be able to measurably answer a question like that.

Comment: I'd expect a compiler for a simple language like Forth could be extremely tiny.

Comment: BTW, the first computer I used, the PDP-8, only had 4K 12-bit words (and no virtual memory). It had compilers for Fortran, BASIC, and FOCAL.

Comment: @Barmar - Never knew about forth until now. Seems to be exotic and esoteric. Why do you think it could be extremely tiny ? Could it be the tiniest if yes, why ?

Comment: Forth has very simple syntax, and not many built-in operations. It's basically just a fancy RPN calculator.

Comment: Back when C was invented, it was first implemented on the PDP-11.  The PDP-11 only supports a program (like the compiler) using 64 KB of code and 64 KB of data.  That may be one reason the original compiler was split up into so many passes (preprocessor, compiler, optimizer, assembler, linker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible.

Check this out: [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/).
Fully working C compiler executable in 135KB (for Win32).
After `upx` it becomes just 72KB.

Comment: Will such small compilers be as useful as the ones made by borland, eclipse or netbeans ? That is, can they be trusted make commercial software.

Comment: Why not - but it may be not heavily optimized. For example, TCC can compile and boot Linux kernel, even at boot time: http://bellard.org/tcc/tccboot.html. and talking about quality compilers from borland - I think most software is compiled by open source `gcc` and `msvc`, and Borland is probably not even in low digits