# When for example, a compiler C is implemented with C language, isn't it caused a loop?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

I can't undestand the compiler topic. 
When, for example a compiler C, is implemented with C language, isn't it caused a loop?
C calls C calls C ....
Thanks in advance

Comment: @hamedbaziyad What code? The question is about a basic theoretical issue in compiler construction. If you don't understand it, leave it to those who do.

Comment: Possibly better duplicates: [Writing a compiler in its own language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193560/implementing-a-compiler-in-itself) and [Bootstrapping a language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537/bootstrapping-a-language)

Comment: No reason to downvote this question, it's perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

A compiler takes a given programming language and converts it to Machine Code. For example, a program written in C will be compiled down to machine code and then perform a task. If you write another compiler, the previous compiler (now in machine code) will compile *that compiler* down to machine code again.

Comment: Thanks , Yes I know, but for C language, we can write a compiler using C code, so for running this compiler, we need C compiler again, I mean we need compiler C for running an implemented Compiler C

Comment: @MRezaei Somewhere back in the past there needs to have been a C compiler written in a different language:possibly for a subset, and possibly in assembler. See the duplicate.